# What does it mean to say a diagram commutes?

Tags: category-theory, smooth-manifolds

$\require{AMScd}$
In the context of smooth manifolds, the map $F:M\rightarrow N$ is smooth if $G$ on the below diagram is smooth.

$\begin{CD}
M @> F > > N\\
@V \varphi V V @V  V\psi V\\
\varphi(U) @> G >=\psi\circ F\circ\varphi^{-1} > \psi(V)
\end{CD}$

Some notes I found say "if and only if this diagram commutes" however this diagram always commutes! if $F$ isn't smooth all it means is $G$ wont be smooth.

What does it mean to say a diagram commutes in this case?

Notes:
http://www.math.toronto.edu/mat1300/smoothmaps.4.pdf

Definition:
http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Smooth_map

Comment: Sure, it commutes. Have you looked at other books on the subject?

Comment: Of course it commutes, I say that. What says the arrows must be smooth, the context? This is the /definition/ of $F$ being smooth @MartinBrandenburg

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg by that I mean if $F$ isn't smooth, it'll still commute! Just $G$ wont be smooth

Answer (score 10):

"The diagram commutes" means exactly what it always means: that the map produced by following any path through the diagram is the same.

The notes you are reading **made a mistake** and forgot to require that $G$ be smooth.

Comment: So "diagram commutes" means "under [whatever] constraints - the diagram makes sense" - my confusion was because nothing says an arrow has to be smooth (otherwise $F$ couldn't have one). When I use diagrams I must specify things like this.

Comment: @Alec: Yes, I understood that that was your confusion. Now I am confused as to whether you understand my answer. I am saying that "a diagram commutes" means **exactly**, and **only** that certain compositions of maps are equal - absolutely nothing about the properties of those maps. I am agreeing with you that yes, it ought to have been said that $G$ was smooth, because the diagram given **always** commutes. The notes provide an incorrect (and in this case, vacuous) definition.

Comment: The following diagram commuting
$$\begin{CD}
A @> w > > B\\
@V x V V @V  Vy V\\
C @> >z > D
\end{CD}$$
means precisely that $y\circ w=z\circ x$.

Comment: I see what you mean - I came very close to "forcing" that in the context of smooth manifolds, I defined arrows to be smooth and "commutative" to mean smooth too - which __you've saved me from doing__

Before upvoting and ticking, http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Smooth_map#Via_commutative_diagrams is that "how I ought to say it" (and last question while I've got you here, what do the curved and dashed arrows mean? - I've not found a book that defines this notion - you've given a superb and unambiguous definition of commutative) - Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think part of the confusion is that the sentence below the definition - "In the above diagram, $G := \Psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(U \cap F^{-1}(V)) \rightarrow \Psi(V)$" - is not meant to be part of the definition, rather it is a clarification. The definition given is that $F$ is smooth iff there exists $G$ (which, from its position in the diagram, is a morphism between open subsets of $\mathbb{R^s}$, that is, is a smooth map*) such that

$\begin{CD}
M @> F > > N\\
@V \varphi V V @V  V\psi V\\
\varphi(U) @> G > > \psi(V)
\end{CD}$

commutes.

*- but I agree this should have been stated explicitly

Does that make things clearer at all?